# Maximum number of perfect matchings in a graph 

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

What is the maximal number of perfect matchings a graph $G(V,E)$ can have if $|V|$ and $|E|$ are fixed? I am particularly interested in a case when $|E| = c|V|^2$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is exactly the main result of [this recent paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V00-4X9D5FW-2&_user=4423&_coverDate=02%2F28%2F2010&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1298182872&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000059605&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=4423&md5=e0f086e2b1298619e290e92b111dc6b8) we just published in *Discrete Mathematics*.  Just in case the link doesn't work: this is "Graphs with the maximum or minimum number of 1-factors" by D. Grossa, N. Kahl and J.T. Saccoman.   I have read only the abstract.  Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this paper really gives the answer. In fact, it seems that the main result was obtained by Alon and Friedland in this paper: http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_15/PDF/v15i1n13.pdf. There they show that graphs which are union of complete bipartite graphs have the maximum number of perfect matchings among all graphs with the same degree sequence.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/j.disc.2009.08.016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2009.08.016) ([Zbl 1214.05120](https://zbmath.org/1214.05120)).

Comment: The link to `emis.ams.org` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/43979) above seems to be broken, but the article can be found at the new website of the [EMIS](https://www.emis.de/journals/EJC/Volume_15/Abstracts/v15i1n13.html), or at [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/117197), or at [arXiv:0803.2578](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2578) [math.CO] ([Zbl 1183.05064](https://zbmath.org/1183.05064)).